# create symbolic links in windows

Tags: magento2.3, windows, pwa, symlinks

How to create symbolic links in magento2 folder for pwa studio installation.
In linux using by

```
   ln command
```

But in windows, How to do?can anyone brief about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command as follows:

```
ln [-fs] [-L|-P] source_path target_path
```

Where,

**-f** Force existing destination pathnames to be removed to allow the link.

**-L** For each source_file operand that names a file that is a symbolic link, create a hard link to the file referenced by the symbolic link.

**-P** For each source_file operand that names a file that is a symbolic link, create a (hard) link to the symbolic link itself.

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: this is for linux os,but i need in windows

Comment: Try this "mklink source_path target_path"