# Magento 2 category image 404 with store code in url

Tags: category, multistore, image, magento2.2.2, media-images

I have a phtml file in my theme that is added to category page via XML updates tab.

I read image in phtml like so:

```
$this->getUrl('media/catalog/category/').$_category->getImageUrl()
```

My theme has 2 store view `nl-be`, `fr-be` and one of them has store code to url like so:

```
NL-BE = https://magento2.com/media/catalog/category/image.jpg


NL-FR = https://magento2.com/fr-be/media/catalog/category/image.jpg //THIS IMAGE GOES 404
```

Anyone any idea?

Comment: have you created symlinks ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to create **Symlinks** for the same Directory.

If you don't know, how to **Symlinks** then please refer this link:

- [For Windows](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284636/create-symbolic-links-in-windows)
- [For Linux](https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux/)

Comment: in my opinion the images should return 200 out of the box I can see that magento native itself doesn't add the store code to any images urls either another options is to use: `<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue("web/unsecure/base_url", "\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES");?>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have having store codes in URL's then to get the media files correctly working you need to add symlinks in the corresponding directory for your store view for media as follows

```
ln -s source destination
```

Example

> ln -s ../pub/media media

This if for linux.